# Java Table model data disappearing

Tags: java

I've run into a very strange issue. I wrote a model for a table and for the most part it works perfect. When I update the row data via the setValueAt function it works and the data in the ArrayList is updated and complete. But when i run the getTotalPay function the same array is empty and i get a null value exception.

I've rewrote the code a number of different ways and tried a couple of different approaches to the problem but the problem persists. I know i've done something wrong i just cannot figure out what the problem is. After search the net and not finding a solution i'm posting this.

Things i've tried are replacing the variable, putting the data into two different variables.

Here is the model

```
public class WeeklyWagesModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private String defaultValue = "Click to edit";
    private String[] headings = { "Date From", "Date To", "Wages", "Pay Date" };

    private ArrayList<String[]> theData = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    public WeeklyWagesModel() {
        theData.add(createDefaultRow());
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return headings.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return headings[col];
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return theData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return theData.get(row)[col];
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {

        theData.get(row)[col] = String.valueOf(value);

        if (row == (theData.size() - 1)) {
            theData.add(createDefaultRow());
        }

        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return String.class;
    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> getData() {
        return theData;
    }

    public String getTotalPay() {
        System.out.println("Total Pay: " + theData.size());
        BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        for (String[] eachRow : theData) {
            if (StringUtils.isNumeric(eachRow[2])) {
                total.add(new BigDecimal(eachRow[2]));
            }
        }

        return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(total);
    }

    public String getTotalWeeks() {
        return "";
    }

    private String[] createDefaultRow() {
        String[] newRow = new String[headings.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < newRow.length; i++) {
            newRow[i] = defaultValue;
        }

        return newRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to try and set the value of a cell, but then check if you need to add a new row...which could cause issues, if you're using `setValueAt` to add new rows

Comment: Are you using the same instance of the table model

Comment: I checked that I'm using the same instance and I am

Comment: would I be better to add the row using a listener for data changes?

Comment: It would be very rare for `setRowValueAt` to be called for a row which doesn't exist, unless you're doing that manually. Personally, I'd have a method in the model which performed the basic add operation